# How to add custom column to serilog MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I have a code line like this in Program.cs

```
Logger log = new LoggerConfiguration()     
.WriteTo.Console()     
.WriteTo.File("logs/log.txt")     
.WriteTo.MySQL(connectionString:builder.Configuration
                            .GetConnectionString("MySqlServer"),
               tableName: "logs")     
.CreateLogger();
```

I want to add custom columns to logs table. I couldn't find any solution of this problem. There are a lot of example for MSSQL but there is no for MySQL.

I want to add custom columns but I couldn't solve it, how can I add custom columns in mysql serilog table?

Comment: Have you installed `Install-Package Serilog.Sinks.MySQL`? How you did configured your appsettings? Could you please inlcude that within your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which sink are you using? There are 10 MySQL sinks in NuGet. The most popular one doesn't allow customizing columns

Comment: Yes, I install sinks.MySQL. I didn't configured my appsettings.  I just want to add a few custom column to logs table.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos which one I should use it? can you give me an example please?

Comment: What custom columns do you want to add? Where will they get their data from? The [MariaDB sink](https://github.com/TeleSoftas/serilog-sinks-mariadb) can work with MySQL, uses the far better [MySqlConnector](https://mysqlconnector.net/) data provider and allows mapping columns to property names through the `PropertiesToColumnsMapping` dictionary. Chances are you're already using MySqlConnector already, either directly or through the Pomelo EF Core provider

Comment: Another option is to use computed columns to extract data from the JSON value stored in `Properties`, using MySQL's JSON functions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for helping me and can you give me an exapmle for how to edit PropertiesToColumnsMapping?

Comment: have you got any working solution for this? even I am also trying for the same

Comment: Here is my code I hope it will be usefull for you
Just add this options to your logs code 
`options: new MariaDBSinkOptions
    {
        PropertiesToColumnsMapping =
        {
            ["UserName"] = "UserName"
        }
    })`